# c++ fill vector in optional class input

Tags: c++, class, templates

I want to have an optional input argument for a templated class, where its number of elements depends on the template. For instance:

```
template< int SomeInteger >
class SomeClass: public SomeOtherClass
{
public:

    Constructor( const std::vector< double > someVector,
                 const std::vector< double > someOptionalVector = { 1, 1, 1, ... } )

}
```

so the total number of 1s, should depend on the value of `SomeInteger`. How can I do that?

Comment: Why `const std::vector<double> someOptionalVector = std::vector<double> (SomeInteger, 1)` Doesn't work for you?

Comment: Perhaps a [vector constructor reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) could be helpful?

Comment: Thank you for the incredibly quick replies! Problem solved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::vector` has a constructor that takes a value and a number of times to add that value into the vector.  You can use that constructor to initialize `someOptionalVector` like

```
Constructor(const std::vector<double> someVector,
            const std::vector<double> someOptionalVector = std::vector<double>(SomeInteger, 1.0))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const std::vector<double> someOptionalVector = std::vector<double>(SomeInteger, 1.0)
```

Yep, that's it. Thank [`std::vector`'s constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) for that ;)